# Program works perfect in Eclipse but when exporting as runnable JAR I get java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, jar

When I execute my code, a server is created while in Eclipse, working perfectly, but when I export it to a runnable JAR I keep getting, I tried many things but I get this error

```
java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
            at java.base/javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLServerSocketFactory.throwException(SSLServerSocketFactory.java:177)
            at java.base/javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(SSLServerSocketFactory.java:190)
            at LibraryServer.startServer(LibraryServer.java:38)
            at ServerEA.main(ServerEA.java:7)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
    Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
            at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1900)
            at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
            at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
            at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:184)
            at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:110)
            at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLServerSocketFactory.java:74)
            at LibraryServer.startServer(LibraryServer.java:36)
            ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.security.KeyManagementException
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder.<clinit>(SSLContextImpl.java:942)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>(SSLContextImpl.java:1112)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
            at java.base/java.security.Provider.newInstanceUtil(Provider.java:155)
            at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1893)
            ... 12 more
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.BufferedReader.readLine()" because "this.in" is null
            at LibraryServer.readIn(LibraryServer.java:151)
            at ServerEA.main(ServerEA.java:9)
            ... 5 more
```

The code that fails is, at the part of **sslserversocket=(SSLServerSocket) f.createServerSocket(port);**:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", getClass().getResource("/resources/server.jks").getFile());
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "contraseña");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType","JKS");
        SSLServerSocketFactory f=(SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
        sslserversocket=(SSLServerSocket) f.createServerSocket(port);
```

If needed, the POM file for the project is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>tfg.servereya</groupId>
  <artifactId>EnrollmentYAuthentication</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  
  <build>
  <plugins>
  
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-resources</id>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/resources/</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
  </plugins>
  
  </build>
  <dependencies>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And the project structure is as shown in this image:

[image]

If more information is needed just ask, sorry for the long question

Comment: You should use `/server.jks`, not `/resources/server.jks`. The `resources` directory is a construct that only exists in your sources, not in the final compiled and packaged program. You should also use `getResourceAsStream`, not `getResource(..).getFile()`, as resources in a packaged program are not files on your file system, but resources in your packaged jar. If you really need it as a file, you need to extract it first.

Comment: thanks for the response, I did as you said and changed it to /server.jks and used the getResourceAsStream, but, of that I get an InputStream as follows:   `InputStream keyStore = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/server.jks");` but I need to pass to `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyStore);` keyStore as string. Tried by passing the input stream through a buffer reader and then to string but it did not work. How can be done? Thanks a lot

Comment: To explain myself better. I do not know how to get the absolutePath with the `getResourceAsStream` as I did before with the `getResource(...).getFile()`, to pass it as a property to the `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyStore)`. I managed to get the content of the file but not the absolute path to it that will be used in the JAR

Comment: The resource does not exist on the file system, it is an entry in the JAR file. If you need it on the file system, you will first need to write it to disk (e.g. to a temporary folder), and then use that, or you need change how you package and deploy your application, for example so that the keystore is an actual file next to your JAR instead of a resource inside the JAR.